# Unable to change permissions on MS Access MSysObjects table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm running this code in a module on Access 2013:

```
Sub grant()
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
End Sub
```

I know it's running because I had a Debug.Print printing out a hello world set up and that worked, but when I try to run a query on the tables I get the CLI no read access error.

I unfortunately need to connect to these tables because I'm trying to run pass-through SQL from another application.

Any thoughts? I'm saving the database after I run the query, and even have opened/closed it and the other application I'm using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't alter the user rights on the system tables. That's by design.

Neither do you have to, as you have read access to this table.

Edit:

You can easily read from it - as in this example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[Id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[Id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca;
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that I'm not supposed to alter the table, but I'm just trying to SELECT from it (eventually I want to know if a field is indexed or not). Is this code the right code for that/is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what GRANT does here. You should need just a SELECT. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry-I'm trying to connect to this database through ODBC and run an explicit pass-through query on the MSysObjects table, and it's from the other application that I'm getting an error.

Is there somewhere from within Access I can run that query to make sure the table is accessible? After talking with you, I bet it's my ODBC connection that's messed up (not passing the right credentials or something) but would like to make sure.

Comment: Oh, forgot that. It may very well be that the ODBC driver excludes system tables as these are "invisible". In Access itself, you must set a mark to have system tables visible, but I don't believe you can do that via ODBC. It is not related to privileges - the standard user is Admin.

Comment: Yep, got in contact with some people who knew more about it than me, and it ended up being an ODBC driver bitness thing. Thanks so much-probably would not have guessed that without your help.